# Get device name, search for a device image, set to ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Is there a way to search for an image and then set the image to an ImageView.
Basically my app is doing this:

-when my app starts I check for Internet Connection

-if No Internet Connection -> I set a default image

-but if there is an Internet Connection I want to get the device name, search on the web and then apply the image to an ImageView

Comment: you can do this, get the response from `https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=<query>` and then parse it to get the URL of the first image.

Comment: Ok, then how do you get URL of the first image?

Comment: [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) will make it easier to parse it, you should find the regex yourself, examine the response from google image search to get a hint.